# Capistrano rails Skipping task `deploy:updating' because it was previously invoked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano, rvm1-capistrano3

I am on rails using rvm,

I get following error when deplying using capistrano:

```
Skipping task `deploy:updating'.
Capistrano tasks may only be invoked once. Since task `deploy:updating' was previously invoked, invoke("deploy:updating") at /home/ziaulrehman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/capistrano-3.8.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:64 will be skipped.
If you really meant to run this task again, first call Rake::Task["deploy:updating"].reenable
THIS BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE IN A FUTURE VERSION OF CAPISTRANO. Please join the conversation here if this affects you.
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1686
```

my capfile has:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/sidekiq'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# there are no customm tasks
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

And my deploy.rb looks something like:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.2"

set :application,     "webapp"
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :keep_releases,   5
set :repo_url,        "git@github.com:org/webapp.git"

append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', '.env.generic'
append :linked_dirs,  'vendor/bundle', 'public/uploads'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to,       "/home/deployer/www/webapp"

set :rvm1_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.3.4'
# set :rvm_type, :user
# set :default_env,      { rvm_bin_path: '~/.rvm/bin' }
# fetch(:default_env).merge!( rvm_path: '~/.rvm/bin' )
set :rvm1_map_bins, -> { fetch(:rvm_map_bins).to_a.concat(%w{rake gem bundle ruby foreman}).uniq }

before 'deploy', 'rvm1:install:ruby'

set :sidekiq_processes => 2
set :keep_assets, 2
set :sidekiq_config =>    '#{release_path}/config/sidekiq.yml'

set :pty, true
```

**I have absolutely no custom task or anything, these are all gems I am using, i suspect some kind of conflict in gems.**

If anyone can point out exactly where this issue is being created and how can I fix this, would be great. Also, i would like to know the implications of the issue. Everything seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem caused by the `rvm1-capistrano3` gem. I took a quick look at that gem's source code on GitHub, and it is doing weird things like registering hooks like this:

```
before :ruby, "deploy:updating"
```

This makes no sense to me; it means that if you invoke `rvm1:install:ruby` at the beginning of a deployment (as suggested by the README), then it will trigger `deploy:updating` before your deploy has even started. That normally is supposed to trigger at the *end* of a deployment. The fact that this gem works at all is surprising.

The `Skipping task` warning is important. Your deploy may work, but it is worrisome nonetheless. I recommend finding an alternative to the `rvm1-capistrano3` gem.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your analysis, this gem is a pretty much standard one. I would open an issue for this problem on the gem repo, and would link this answer there. This is in active development and usage so it would be weird if it is ok for all other users of the gem and only I am having the issue. But still, as of your analysis it deserves an issue. Thanks